# Redirecting off-topic questions somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

We sometimes get questions that aren't on-topic or a good fit for SharePoint.SE. For third party questions, this is easy because we can redirect the user to the particular company's support site.

However, for other questions like polls, open-ended discussions, or other-wise open-ended questions there currently is no place we recommend for users.

Is there somewhere we can point users to discuss these types of questions and get the answers/discussion they are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN forums :)

Anything else is more or less promotion of some other 'competitive' service.

Comment: Hmm good idea. I guess we would just point people to the [forum index](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories)?

Answer (score 0):

An option to consider would be [/r/sharepoint](http://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint) on reddit. The community there is smaller but I think reddit is better suited for discussion in the comments.

I reached out to one of the mods over there and I think they are receptive. :)